# Why is my 'America/New_York' timezone be a CWST time in php

Tags: php, timezone

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');

echo date('e').'</br>';

echo date('T').'</br>';
```

it  output:

```
CWST

America/New_York.
```

It Seems to be the  system timezone set (+0845)  (Australia/Eucla [CWST +08:45])

I tried some other timezone and won't  have this problem.

Comment: What version of PHP are you running?

Comment: It's  5.3.3  by  `php -v`  commond

Comment: It's  5.3.3  by  `php -v`  commond

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to reproduce this. [See output here](http://ideone.com/OjCoQf).

If your system time zone is really `"Australia/Eucla"`, then I suppose that perhaps there's a bug in PHP.  The 45-minute offset might be part to blame.  But its very odd that it would affect the abbreviation.  If anything, I'd expect it to affect only the offset.

If this is a server we're talking about, you may want to consider setting the system time zone to UTC.  There aren't a lot of good reasons to localize the time zone of a server (of any kind).

I suppose it's also possible that your copy of the time zone data is just corrupted.  You might try to re-install [the timezonedb package](http://pecl.php.net/package/timezonedb) from pecl.